# Stop service of Application When Windows Start

Tags: c#, windows-10

```
RegistryKey reg = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
reg.SetValue("MyApp", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
reg.Close();
```

From this code, I am able to auto-start my app at the start of windows. (like Skype)
But I want to stop auto-running my app through c# coding. Anyone knows the code of it??

Comment: RegistryKey has a method called [DeleteValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba304x5k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I am unable to delete it from this metjod.

Comment: And why can you not delete it?

Answer (score 0):

I give an optional setting in my application about auto run. If radio Button yes is checked then app should have run automatically but if radio button no is checked then it should not run automatically.

Below is my coding but through it I am not able to stop my app from auto-running.

```
    private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    if (btnno.Checked == true)
        {
            DisposeStartup();
        }
        else if (btnyes.Checked == true)
        {
            ActivateStartup();
        }
    }

    private void ActivateStartup()
    {
        reg.SetValue("MyApp", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
        reg.Close();
    }
        private void DisposeStartup()
         {
        if (reg != null)
        {
            reg.DeleteValue("MyApp", true);
            reg.Close();
        }
    }
```